# Angular App: bootstrap navbar doesn't show up on small screen sizes

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am making an angular app (angular 11.2.4 with bootstrap 4.5.3) and the `navbar` is not rendering properly on screen sizes less than ~580 pixels wide.

along the bar I can click the toggler and 'expand' the collapse region, but still nothing is rendered. This is also what is rendered when the bar is a fixed regular `navbar`

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark fixed-top hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#" routerLink="/resume">Resume</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white"  href="#" routerLink="/projects">Projects</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/">
                <img src="../../assets/github_icon.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
              </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <nav class = "navbar visible-xs visible-sm">
    
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left"
      type="button"
      aria-controls="mobileNavbar"
      aria-expanded="false"
      [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" 
      aria-label="Toggle mobile navigation"
      (click)="toggleMenu()"
      >
      <span class="dark-blue-text"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-1x">

      </i></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mobileNavbar" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#" routerLink="/resume">Resume</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white"  href="#" routerLink="/projects">Projects</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-navbar',
  templateUrl: './main-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-navbar.component.css']
})
export class MainNavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  isCollapsed = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggleMenu() 
  {
    this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `hidden-sm hidden-xs` from your `nav` tag's class.

**Edit:**

Ignore the previous answer. Add `bg-dark` to your second nav class.

```
<nav class="navbar bg-dark visible-xs visible-sm">
```

Working demo at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dv7he1?file=src/app/Navigation/main-navbar.component.html).

Comment: I have two ```navbars```: one for mobile and one for desktop. I use the ```hidden-sm hidden-xs``` and ```visible-xs visible-sm``` to control which ```navbar``` will appear. That functionality works fine. The problem is the bar is not rendered correctly on smaller screens.

Comment: thank you for your help. Your demo solved the problem and got me on the right track.